# When to use version or build in Apple app store connect?

Tags: ios

My question is when you upload a build to App Store Connect, you have Version number and build number. A Version number change triggers a App Review (this can take sometime to approve) and just a build change happens fairly immediately. So is there a guide line when to make a version change or just a build change?

Answer (score 1):

The build number indicates a specific build for a specific version.
For example you can have 5 builds for version 1.0.2.
Every time you want to publish a version you need to specify which build of that version is going for approve.

When you want to submit an app update you must increase the version number, you can't submit again the same version.

If your current version is 1.0.2, build number 13, your next version can be 1.0.3, build number 1.